# How to specify colour in a single 32 bit value

Tags: android, opengl-es2

I'm writing my first game using OpenGL 2 ES (for Android), and I've currently got a particle engine and some player sprites running successfully.  I'm using 4 floats for the colour of each particle which seems like total overkill.  It makes sense that I should be able to use a single 32 bit int (or perhaps a single float) to hold the colours (perhaps in RGBA format) which would presumably save a lot of unnecessary loading/copying/processing,  but I'm struggling to understand how I could do this.

I guess that I would need to change the shaders to take the relevant format, and also i'd need to change the way I load the color shader attribute.  My fragment shader has:

```
varying vec4 v_Color;
gl_FragColor = v_Color * texture2D(u_TextureUnit, gl_PointCoord);
```

and the attribute (passed into the fragment shader from the vertex shader) is set up with:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(aColourLocation, COLOUR_COMPONENT_COUNT, GL_FLOAT, false, BYTES_PER_VERTEX, floatBuffer);
```

I've searched the documentation for what I should change vec4 and GL_FLOAT to, and what/how I'd multiply the colour with the texture, and have tried a few things but with no success.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place you should set the draw buffer to a 8 bit format, all the rest happens automatically

Comment: @ratchetfreak Not sure what i'd do to the shader/attrib setup. What types do I use?  How do I do the colour multiply?

Comment: this might help http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format

Comment: @Aralox Thanks, that seems relevant. Seems that what I want would be GL_RGBA8UI. Sadly, it doesn't look like this is available on OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html#GL_RGB Or am I misreading that?  Should I be worried about trying to use 4 bytes instead of 16 to specify the colour of each particle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragment shaders operate with floats.  This is an abstraction over the actual underlying hardware format (GLSL is a high-level language after all), so you shouldn't expect that to indicate that you've actually got a floating-point framebuffer.  You'll always use vec4 in your fragment shader irrespective of if you have a 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit or 128-bit framebuffer, and there's no memory overhead for doing so.

There's no need to change your fragment shader; don't fall into the trap of thinking that the high-level GLSL you write is any way representative of the low-level hardware instructions that actually run.

For sending colours as a 4-byte format you adjust your glVertexAttribPointer call so that it's using GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE for the *type* parameter and GL_TRUE for the *normalized* parameter.  Then also adjust your source data, and you can start sending colours as 4 bytes with a 0-255 range, in RGBA order.  The hardware will automatically convert them to floats in a 0-1 range and your fragment shader, once again, remains exactly the same as before.  Don't sweat the details of whether or not this is a slow operation: it isn't.

Beware of thinking you're going to be even more efficient if you decide to only send 3-bytes sometimes: hardware prefers to operate on 32-bit boundaries and while you will save a small amount of memory you risk running substantially slower as a result.

Comment: I guess I have to have an array of ints with which to feed the colour attribute, given that were I to continue to use a float there'd be some corruption to my RGBA int.  (When changing my code to take your answer into account I discovered that I had to use ABGR format within my ints (the alpha is in the 8 most significant bits).   I guess this is an endian thing - i'm using the native order in my IntBuffer)